# row_number() function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to use the `row_number` function in a view?

I use it like this:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name ASC), 
    name, family, mobile, tell
FROM  
    dbo.customer
```

but SQL Server throws this error:

> SQL text cannot be represented in the grid pane and diagram pane.

Comment: The error is: _"SQL text cannot be represented in the grid pane and diagram pane"_? The query designer doesn't support `row_number`. Try your query in a normal sql query editor. The query designer is almost useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` in a view, but you need to give it a name to use in a view:

```
SELECT row_number() over (order by name asc) as seqnum,
       name, family, mobile, tell
FROM dbo.customer;
```

Comment: I Do It But give me Same Error

Comment: your answer is perfect but in datagrid_view this columns content not display

Answer (score 1):

The error is: *"SQL text cannot be represented in the grid pane and diagram pane"*?

Well, the query designer doesn't support `row_number`. Try your query in a normal sql query editor. The [query designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/graphical-query-designer-user-interface) is almost useless because it still has bugs and lacks many things(like this).

You should also give it a name:

```
SELECT ColName = row_number()over(order by name asc), name, family, mobile, tell
FROM  dbo.customer
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your column `[name]`, and that it's of the data type `text`. That particular data type has been deprecated since 2000/2005 iirc.

If you need to be doing sort operations on your `[name]` column, it'll need to be a different datatype. You should be using a `(n)varchar(MAX)`.